# Trying to create a function where I can search through my database and get search results. Errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, search

I have found this code online and used it exactly, but it keeps giving me errors:

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Books_model::get_search(), called in controller on line 23 and defined

CONTROLLER

function search()
{
$data['query'] = $this->Books_model->get_search();
$this->load->view(‘books’, $data);
}

MODEL

function get_search()
{
$match = $this->input->post(‘search’);
$this->db->like(‘bookname’,$match);
$this->db->or_like(‘author’,$match);
$this->db->or_like(‘characters’,$match);
$this->db->or_like(‘synopsis’,$match);
$query = $this->db->get(‘books’);
return $query->result();
}

VIEWS

<?=form_open(‘books/search’);?>
<?php $search = array(‘name’=>’search’,'id’=>’search’,'value’=>”,);?>
<?=form_input($search);?><input type=submit value=’Search’ /></p>
<?=form_close();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
function search()
{
  $match = $this->input->post(‘search’);
  $data['query'] = $this->Books_model->get_search($match);
  $this->load->view(‘books’, $data);
}
```

Model

```
function get_search($match = NULL)
{
   $this->db->like(‘bookname’,$match);
   $this->db->or_like(‘author’,$match);
   $this->db->or_like(‘characters’,$match);
   $this->db->or_like(‘synopsis’,$match);
   $query = $this->db->get(‘books’);
   return $query->result();
}
```

Views

```
<?=form_open(‘books/search’);?>
<?php $search = array(‘name’=>’search’,'id’=>’search’,'value’=>”,);?>
<?=form_input($search);?><input type=submit value=’Search’ /></p>
<?=form_close();?>
```

Comment: When I try to view it I get: 404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.